# MS SQL - insert data from one Table into another using Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have few data's in Table_1 & want to insert the data into Table_2.

Is it possible to perform this operation using Trigger function in MS SQL?

Also I want this to data to insert into table_2 automatically in a specific time.

Can this be performed using SQL Trigger?

New to SQL...

Comment: You can perform an `INSERT` from a trigger, yes, but I can't see why you would need to. If you want to insert data from one table to another then why not simply a `INSERT INTO...SELECT... FROM` style statement? Why do want/need to do it in a trigger?

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate our data?

Comment: Okay...But I cant able to run the sql script all the time...I want the query to run automatically...like scheduling process

Comment: Take a step back, and have a look at your question from the perspective of someone that knows nothing about your system, or requirements and read it. Could you answer? We're all volunteers here that have no experience or knowledge of you, your system, and only a very vague description of your goal(s). Perhaps instead you could show us your requirements in data. Post the DDL and DML of your first table, and then explain what data you want in your other table, and when. As @jarlh asked, why do you need to duplicate the data? Perhaps you're trying to create a log/audit table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps an *instead of* trigger could be of use?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [schema_name.] trigger_name
ON {table_name | view_name }
INSTEAD OF {[INSERT] [,] [UPDATE] [,] [DELETE] }
AS
{sql_statements}
```

Note though that you will have to insert into both tables in the trigger as you are "overriding" the standard `INSERT`.